# Django's loaddata giving ValidationError on valid date

Tags: python, django, datefield, validationerror

I'm trying to use fixtures in Django to provide some initial data to one of my projects. The model that I want to provide this data to has a DateField named 'added'. So in the JSON file that contains my fixture, I included the following line:

```
"added": "2011-11-11",
```

When I load this file using

```
python manage.py loaddata test.json
```

I get this error

```
ValidationError: [u'Enter a valid date in YYYY-MM-DD format.']
```

so I tried using dumpdata to find out how the internal formatting is different from what I did

```
python manage.py dumpdata modelname > bla.json
```

but it contains the same line that I used:

```
"added": "2011-11-11",
```

What do I have to do to use dates in my JSON files? I really can't see where I went wrong, since my formatting is identical to what dumpdate gives me.

Nearly all of my models contain DateFields and I need the data from the fixtures to test my application.

Comment: did you run your json through lint just to make sure it is valid?

Comment: Going to need more information, this should work fine normally.

Comment: The project uses Python 2.7.2 and Django 1.3.1. I am using SQLite as my database and storing dates from within my application (i.e. a form on a web site) works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, date format in Django fixtures must be **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss**.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem try to use 2011-11-11T16:52:11

Comment: Note: This is valid for MySQL, but not PostgreSQL. The latter would need the format `2011-11-11 16:52:11`.

Comment: Really? I was having the OP's problem loading from fixtures to MySQL. I changed all the 'T's to spaces in the dumped JSON and that fixed the problem. Anyway, how do I change the date format when creating fixtures (so that it would use ' ' instead of 'T')?